# Spring Logback %d not setting dates in file names

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-logback

I have a Spring boot app ( the backend... ) and I want to configure the naming of a logfile with the current date, but after alot of searches, I still can't seem to be able to get it to work.
I'm using *logback-spring.xml* to set some rules, I set them differently for 'testing' purposes but the problem remains:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />
    <property name="ERROR" value="./logs/errors" />
    <property name="DEBUG" value="./logs/debug" />

    <appender name="Console"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{dd-MM-yyyy} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>200MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingErrorFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${ERROR}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${ERROR}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <totalSizeCap>30MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingDebugFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEBUG}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEBUG}/debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <totalSizeCap>30MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>


    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>

    <!-- LOG "x" at ERROR level -->
    <logger name="x" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingErrorFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingDebugFile" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

So I've set an extra *%d{yyyy-MM-dd}* in the error part to see what would happen, but of course the naming gives this result: *error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log*
If I don't add it in the naming itself, the fileNamePattern doesn't fill anything in and I'd just get a error.log.
In the debug-configuration I also added a *%d{yyyy-MM-dd}* in the pattern-property of the encoder but again it's not picked up when I run it.

I've already searched and found that the class should be '*ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender* ' but that doesn't fix it neither.